# porque me arroja localhost:8080 mi configuracion en webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

En la siguiente linea se podra apreciar mi configuracion la cual es simple,
ya que estoy aprendiendo webpack, el problema es que al ejecutar el con "npm run start",
me arroja el localhost a 8080 cuando el port es 3005.

NOTA: cabe recalcar que el script de mi package.json esta asi:

** package.json

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "webpack serve",
"build": "webpack --mode production" 
}
```

**webpack config:

```
const path = require('path'); 
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
entry: './src/index',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'main.js',
},
resolve: { //para resolver las extensiones
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js|jsx$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }]
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: [
                { loader: 'html-loader' }
            ]
        },
    ]
},
plugins:[
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './public/index.html',
        filename: './index.html'
    })
],
devServer: {
    static: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 3005
}
}
```

Comment: Ya buscaste en otros archivos de ejecución?? Porque es normal el puerto 8080, talvez el config que tienes no es el que inicializa tu programa

Answer (score 2):

Tenes que decirle al cli de webpack que configuración quieres utilizar con el comando --config [ruta de la configuracion], por ejemplo:

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "webpack serve --config ./webpack.config.js",
"build": "webpack --mode production" 
}
```

Comment: agrege el las opciones faltantes al script y me arrojo error indicando lo siguiente:    
                                                                                                                       webpack Dev Server Invalid Options

options should NOT have additional properties

Comment: Cuales son las opciones faltantes?